# Arduino WiFi Rev 2 & INA219 Incompatible?

Tags: arduino-uno

Using the Adafruit INA219 sample code gives incorrect results when run on a Arduino Uno va Arduino WiFi Rev 2.  On the Uno I use pins A4 and A5 and on the WiFi Rev 2 I use SCL and SDA. I'm guessing the on board WiFi is somehow interfering but can find no reference this that.  The code works find on the Uno. Does anyone have a hint as to where I should look?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_INA219.h>

Adafruit_INA219 ina219;


void setup(void) 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
      // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens
      delay(1);
  }
    
  Serial.println("Hello!");
  
  // Initialize the INA219.
  // By default the initialization will use the largest range (32V, 2A).  However
  // you can call a setCalibration function to change this range (see comments).
  if (! ina219.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find INA219 chip");
    while (1) { delay(10); }
  }
  // To use a slightly lower 32V, 1A range (higher precision on amps):
  //ina219.setCalibration_32V_1A();
  // Or to use a lower 16V, 400mA range (higher precision on volts and amps):
  //ina219.setCalibration_16V_400mA();

  Serial.println("Measuring voltage and current with INA219 ...");
}

void loop(void) 
{
  float shuntvoltage = 0;
  float busvoltage = 0;
  float current_mA = 0;
  float loadvoltage = 0;
  float power_mW = 0;

  shuntvoltage = ina219.getShuntVoltage_mV();
  busvoltage = ina219.getBusVoltage_V();
  current_mA = ina219.getCurrent_mA();
  power_mW = ina219.getPower_mW();
  loadvoltage = busvoltage + (shuntvoltage / 1000);
  
  Serial.print("Bus Voltage:   "); Serial.print(busvoltage); Serial.println(" V");
  Serial.print("Shunt Voltage: "); Serial.print(shuntvoltage); Serial.println(" mV");
  Serial.print("Load Voltage:  "); Serial.print(loadvoltage); Serial.println(" V");
  Serial.print("Current:       "); Serial.print(current_mA); Serial.println(" mA");
  Serial.print("Power:         "); Serial.print(power_mW); Serial.println(" mW");
  Serial.println("");

  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: run the I2CScanner sketch

Comment: I did that and the address is the default of 0x40. I also see what I presume to be the WiFi device with an address of 0x60. I tried connecting to a non WiFi board that has SCL & SDA and get the same results (using the INA219) but still when I use the older Arduino w/o SCL & SDA, I get the results I would expect.